# Passing props to child's child React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, react-props

Good day, I'm trying to pass props to child's child component

example:

parent:

```
Onboarding()

<FilesOnboarding render={Onboarding}/>
```

FilesOnboarding:

```
updateFiles = () => {
 props.render()

}

<ProofFiles props.render={anotherRender?}> 

This is already wrong because I can't pass props.render={anotherRender}
```

ProofFiles

```
updateFiles = () => {
 props.anotherRender()

}
```

Comment: May you update your example so that it shows the code you've already tried? You might also be thinking of "render props".

Comment: okay, just updated it

Answer (score 1):

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-swirles-7hg6g?file=/src/App.js:66-121)

**Parent**

```
function Onboarding() {
  return <h2> Rendering from Parent component </h2>;
}

function Parent() {
  return <FilesOnboarding render={Onboarding} />;
}
```

**FilesOnBoarding**

```
function renderFromFilesOnBoarding() {
  return <h2> Rendering from FilesOnboarding component </h2>;
}

export default function Parent({ render }) {
  return (
    <>
      {render()}
      <ProofFiles anotherRender={renderFromFilesOnBoarding} />
    </>
  );
}
```

**ProofFiles**

```
function Parent({ anotherRender }) {
  return anotherRender();
}
```

Comment: Calling `render()` , `anotherRender()` will lose state on every render, you need to invoke `React.createElement` ie: `Render = render, <Render/>`